# python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

given a file that looks like this:

```
mmm     55  v1235

mmm     111 v1241

mmm     22  v2453

mmm     1   v3464

mmm     555 v5353
```

I want the result to be ( replace all digits with white spaces):

```
mmm         v1235

mmm         v1241

mmm         v2453

mmm         v3464

mmm         v5353
```

Well I can find the length subtract and and turn to white space.
can I do it in one line ?

something like that, but in sub second parameter is a string and not a regex:

`new_line = re.sub(r'mmm     \d+', r'mmm     \s+', line)`

Comment: Why not just: `line = re.sub(r'\d', ' ', line);`

Comment: @anubhava you are correct, sorry edited the question

Comment: ok in that case use: `line = re.sub(r'\d(?=\d* )', ' ', line);`

Answer (score 1):

Using a lookahead you can check if a matching digit is followed by 0 or more digits and a space as:

```
line = re.sub(r'\d(?=\d* )', ' ', line);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KuWWUd/3)

`(?=\d* )` is positive lookahead that asserts we have 0 or more digits and a space next to a matching digit.

Answer (score 0):

`new_line = re.sub(r'mmm\s\d+\s?v', 'mmm         v', line)`

Seems work?

Answer (score 0):

You may put the `mmm` with 5 spaces into a lookbehind and process the match  within a lambda expression:

```
import re
s = '''mmm     55  v

mmm     111 v

mmm     22  v

mmm     1   v

mmm     555 v'''
res = re.sub(r'(?<=mmm {5})[0-9]+', lambda x: " "*len(x.group()), s)
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qDEf4A).

The `(?<=mmm {5})[0-9]+` pattern matches 1 or more digits that are preceded with `mmm` and 5 regular spaces. The `lambda x: " "*len(x.group())` code replaces the digits with the same amount of spaces.

Or just wrap the two parts of the pattern with capturing groups and use `.group(1)` and `.group(2)`:

```
res = re.sub(r'(mmm     )([0-9]+)', lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), " "*len(x.group(2))), s)
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/SxJdZQ).